# Firebase fcm sendMulticast Error: "Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using version 7.2.0 of firebase admin to send fcm push notification, using `sendMutlicast` method:

```
async function sendPushRequest({tokens, title, body, customData}) => {    
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title,
      body,
    },
    data: customData,
    tokens,
  }
  return firebase.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
...
```

I tried logging the data and here is the object that sendPushRequest function is called with:

```
{
  tokens: [ null, null, null, 'home-test', null, null ], // this one is a recent sample, I've been getting this error for a while now
  title: 'some string',
  body: 'some other string',
  customData: {
    title: 'some string',
    body: 'some other string',
    bigText: 'again another string',
    color: '#9f0e27',
    smallIcon: 'notificon',
    sound: 'default'
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the error!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this problem too, its quite difficult to configure google admin firebase in nodejs. I find out there is a package that can handle this nicely.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-notification

but it has some little problem . you can not pass it multiple firebase configuration. here is some example :

```
const fcm = require('fcm-notification');
const fcm_key = require('../config/customer/fcm.json');
const FcM = new fcm(fcm_key);

module.exports.sendToSingleUser = async (message, token) => {
    let message_body = {
        notification: {
            ...message
        },
        token: token
    };
    FcM.send(message_body, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            return err
        } else {
            return response
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Looks like a good library for my current needs. I will probably try that in a refactor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facing this error too. Figure out that our tokens array contains `null` or `undefiend` value. Resolved by remove that from tokens array and everything works fine.